# cinnamon not installing in ubuntu 13.04

Tags: 13.04, cinnamon

I have been trying to install cinnamon in my ubuntu 13.04 and when i give

```
sudo apt-get install cinnamon
```

I get the error as:

```
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies: 
 cinnamon : Depends: libgjs0-libmozjs185-1.0
        Recommends: nemo but it is not going to be installed
        Recommends: cinnamon-screensaver but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Comment: Have you added proper PPA?

Comment: yes i have executed a ppa command

Comment: Which PPA did you add?

Comment: add-apt-repository ppa:gwendal-lebihan-dev/cinnamon-stable

Comment: the ppa has been updated please check now , sudo apt-get update > then > sudo apt-get install cinnamon

Comment: you may consider using `aptitude`, a user-interface that covers `apt-get`'s functionality. it often provides better insight on dependency problems.

Comment: This will happen when you have installed Gnome.
install Aptitude, then do 'sudo aptitude install cinnamon'
respond 'n' to the first solution, and it will give a second solution which is to downgrade Gnome and install the correct version!

Answer (score 3):

This happened to me when I had already install Gnome onto ubuntu.

After install Aptitude and using it to install, it gave me the option to downgrade Gnome in order to install Cinnamon. If you do this Cinnamon should install.

```
$ sudo apt-get install aptitude
$ sudo aptitude install cinnamon
[sudo] password for <USER>: 
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  cinnamon{b} gir1.2-muffin-3.0{a} libmuffin0{a} muffin-common{a} 
0 packages upgraded, 4 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 2,255 kB of archives. After unpacking 9,065 kB will be used.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cinnamon : Depends: libgjs0-libmozjs185-1.0 which is a virtual package.
            Depends: libmozjs185-1.0 (>= 1.8.5-1.0.0+dfsg) but it is not going to be installed.
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Keep the following packages at their current version:
1)     cinnamon [Not Installed]                           



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] n
The following actions will resolve these dependencies:

     Install the following packages:                                                           
1)     libmozjs185-1.0 [1.8.5-1.0.0+dfsg-4 (raring)]                                           

     Downgrade the following packages:                                                         
2)     gjs [1.36.1+js17-0ubuntu1~raring0 (now, raring) -> 1.34.0-0ubuntu1 (raring)]            
3)     gnome-shell [3.8.1-0ubuntu1~raring1.2 (now, raring) -> 3.6.3.1-0ubuntu6 (raring)]       
4)     gnome-shell-common [3.8.1-0ubuntu1~raring1.2 (now, raring) -> 3.6.3.1-0ubuntu6 (raring)]
5)     gnome-sushi [3.8.0-1~ubuntu13.04.2 (now, raring) -> 3.6.1-0ubuntu1 (raring)]            
6)     libgjs0c [1.36.1+js17-0ubuntu1~raring0 (now, raring) -> 1.34.0-0ubuntu1 (raring)]       



Accept this solution? [Y/n/q/?] y
The following packages will be DOWNGRADED:
  gjs gnome-shell gnome-shell-common gnome-sushi libgjs0c 
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  cinnamon gir1.2-muffin-3.0{a} libmozjs185-1.0{a} libmuffin0{a} muffin-common{a} 
0 packages upgraded, 5 newly installed, 5 downgraded, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 4,992 kB of archives. After unpacking 12.4 MB will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n/?] y
```

you will have to input the 'n' and two 'y's in order to install.

Answer (score 0):

This is a relatively easy fix, at least an easy one to try! :) It appears you have a broken dependency/package, an easy fix.

Do this:

```
sudo apt-get clean && sudo apt-get update
```

It should fix your broken packages error, then you can run the `sudo apt-get install cinammon` command to install it!

Good Luck!

Comment: no.. I get the same result

Comment: hmm..? I dunno then.

Comment: Try this command, worth a shot: `sudo apt-get install -f`

Comment: this doesnt work too..

Answer (score 0):

The issue seems to be with the pin priority with the PPA. This should fix the issue.

Open the preferences file:

```
    gksu gedit /etc/apt/preferences
```

Then add this at the bottom:

```
    Package: *
    Pin: origin ppa.launchpad.net
    Pin-Priority: 700
```

Save and close the file and open your terminal to update your packages then install cinnamon.

```
    sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install cinnamon
```

That should work.

I have switched to Linux Mint 15 for my personal distro choice and this is what I had to do to get the latest release of cinnamon and nemo on my machine.

Comment: In Ubuntu 13.04, there is no such file. But there is /etc/apt/preferences.d folder. Also no such inside it. So where can I find that file ?