# How do you fix unmet dependency when installing Cinnamon on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: 14.04, apt, dependencies, cinnamon, aptitude

How do you fix unmet dependency when installing Cinnamon on Ubuntu 14.04?

I attached a bunch of info on what I've tried so far.

---

Attempt 1:

So I found this question on [how-to install cinnamon on ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/94201/how-do-i-install-the-cinnamon-desktop). I tried the first ppa repository and it failed with "unmet dependency... cinnamon-screensaver".

Attempt 2:

I then used ppa-purge to get rid of that repository. Then did apt-get clean. Then I tried the second ppa repository in the how-to guide. I tried to install cinnamon again... and it failed the same way:

```
root@wheaton-ubuntu14:~# apt-get install cinnamon
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cinnamon : Depends: cinnamon-screensaver (>= 2.6.0) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

Attempt 3:

I then looked up [how to fix unmet dependencies and found this guide with 300+ upvotes](https://askubuntu.com/questions/140246/how-do-i-resolve-unmet-dependencies-after-adding-a-ppa) so I thought I was all set!

Attempt 4:

I then saw [someone was successful](https://askubuntu.com/questions/291495/cinnamon-not-installing-in-ubuntu-13-04) with `aptitude install cinnamon`. But every time aptitude said "is this solution acceptable" cinnamon was still marked as "not installed". So I interrupted the interactive process.

Attempt 5:

I google'd the error and saw a [debian thread somewhere with "oh there's a bug fix in git." but then the thread ends with "oh thanks" but no instructions on how to fix the issue.](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=790713)

Not sure where to go from here.

---

update - [as per a request in the comments](https://askubuntu.com/questions/697966/how-do-you-fix-unmet-dependency-when-installing-cinnamon-on-ubuntu-14-04#comment1021898_697966) here is the requested info:

```
root@wheaton-ubuntu14:~# lsb_release -a; uname -a; apt-cache policy cinnamon cinnamon-screensaver; apt-get install cinnamon-screensaver
No LSB modules are available.
Distributor ID: Ubuntu
Description:    Ubuntu 14.04.1 LTS
Release:    14.04
Codename:   trusty
Linux wheaton-ubuntu14 3.13.0-66-generic #108-Ubuntu SMP Wed Oct 7 15:20:27 UTC 2015 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
cinnamon:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.6.12ubuntu1
  Version table:
     2.6.12ubuntu1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/lestcape/cinnamon/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
cinnamon-screensaver:
  Installed: (none)
  Candidate: 2.6.4ubuntu1
  Version table:
     2.6.4ubuntu1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/lestcape/cinnamon/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Some packages could not be installed. This may mean that you have
requested an impossible situation or if you are using the unstable
distribution that some required packages have not yet been created
or been moved out of Incoming.
The following information may help to resolve the situation:

The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 cinnamon-screensaver : Depends: gir1.2-webkit2-3.0 but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

---

update 2 - another request from A.B user: [see here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/13261815/)

Comment: @A.B. As per your request the question is updated.

Comment: I'm coming from a Fedora 21 environment where cinnamon can be installed via 10 second `yum install cinnamon` ... so I am not familiar Ubuntu/apt-get/dpkg/etc.

Comment: @A.B. [see here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/13261815/)

Comment: @A.B. [see here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/13262052/)

Comment: Answer done. Have fun.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The package

```
cinnamon-screensaver
```

depends on

```
gir1.2-webkit2-3.0
```

and this depends on

```
gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-3.0 (= 2.4.0-1ubuntu2)
```

(you haven't enabled `trusty-updates`, but that's not the problem).

Your problem is, that you have installed (manually or earlier by a PPA or something else) the version `2.4.3-1ubuntu2`, as you can see in the [output of the command which you have run](http://paste.ubuntu.com/13262052/):

```
# apt-cache policy gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-3.0
gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-3.0:
  Installed: 2.4.3-1ubuntu2
  Candidate: 2.4.3-1ubuntu2
  Version table:
 *** 2.4.3-1ubuntu2 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.4.0-1ubuntu2 0
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
```

---

The solution is easier than you think:

Downgrade the package and because there is no repository with the wrong version in your system, we're done.

```
sudo apt-get install gir1.2-javascriptcoregtk-3.0=2.4.0-1ubuntu2
sudo apt-get install -f
```

Comment: apt-get install cinnamon still fails with "unmet dependency cinnamon-screensaver" http://paste.ubuntu.com/13262841/

Comment: however... when I tried `aptitude install cinnamon` I think I may be in luck because it seems to be installing... i'll post a pastebin for the output of the aptitude install:  http://paste.ubuntu.com/13262967/

Comment: I logged out... And now my graphics are all broken. Probably something caused by the new cinnamon install.

Comment: Run `sudo apt-get install cinnamon-screensaver` again and give me the output.

Comment: Please see the most recent pastebin where I did apt-get install cinnamon and that installed cinnamon-screensaver

Comment: Ok, I have seen the output, but there are no errors only a warning.

Comment: And this warning ... perhaps with `sudo apt-get install python-minimal`, but this package *should* already be installed.

Comment: alright. restart seems to have fixed it. i am good to go I think. you were right about the downgrade from 2.4.3 to 2.4.0. the important part from the most recent pastebin shows: `Downgrade the following packages:` `1)     libjavascriptcoregtk-3.0-0 [2.4.3-1ubuntu2 (now) -> 2.4.0-1ubuntu2 (trusty)]` `2)     libwebkitgtk-3.0-0 [2.4.3-1ubuntu2 (now) -> 2.4.0-1ubuntu2 (trusty)]`. You were right about the downgrade being the thing to do.